# How is a message verified from a hashed and encrypted version of the message?

Tags: hash

My understanding till now  is that when a message is hashed, it cannot be reconstructed back from the hash.

When the hash is calculated and sent along with message, the attacker can change the message as well as calculate the new hash. And send the new message and the new hash to the receiver. So how are authenticity, integrity   achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by "message is hashed and encrypted" and why would you do that?

Comment: As it would be difficult to sign the signature for whole Message,normal it would be done 1st hash the message and sign with private key and later at the receiver its verified by using the public key.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r2BzB8P6Nk.

Comment: Signing involves a hash, yes. But it's completely unrelated to encryption. And it assumes that the verifier knows both the message and signature they're trying to verify, so reconstructing the message is a moot point.

Comment: As to achieve non-repudiation. The hash would be signed with private key,so receiver can be sure that message has been sent from the real user by verifying it with public key of sender. Therefore now private and public keys are used for signing and verification. Does the  message encryption is done in this case?

Comment: you already know that it is signed, so your question is odd: authenticity is achieved through signing

Comment: I guess you got me wrong, when attacker completely changes the message and replace the hash calculated by the original sender. now the receiver know its altered and discards it . if the same thing keeps on repeating as result receiver wouldn't receive any valid data. How is this solved as now receiver is completely blocked as every message is altered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash is only used for integrity check.
First you encrypt the plaintext using session keys and then compute the MAC of cipher text.
So you send (CipherText, MAC_Of_Cipher)
On receiver side, we compute MAC of Cipher text(using MAC Key) and if both received MAC and calculated MAC matches, message is authentic and we proceed to decrypt the message.

MAC provided **authenticity** as well as **integrity** of message while hash only provide **integrity** check.

Session keys and MAC Key are generated at both ends  while creating secure tunnel like TLS.

Comment: one question now .if the attacker is not really interested in the knowing what data is being send ,but interested in destroying the communication. attacker starts monitoring the (CipherText, MAC_Of_Cipher) as he don't understand the Cipher text ,neither MAC_Of_Cipher he just append the some data to it to destroy the integrity. so now how this can be handled???

Comment: If attacker append some data to cipher text , calculated MAC will mismatch MAC_Of_Cipher. If attacker append some data to MAC of cipher text , then again its a mismatch. So both cases are handled, this Ecrypt-then-MAC is most safest mechanism used to provide authenticity and integrity along with encryption.

Comment: Thanks again!!!! Here my point how the attach's from middle man who wanted to disturb the communication between the sender and receiver are handled. As he(middle man) is not interested to alter some data and make it feel data to receiver as it is comes from the valid user. The only intention of the middle man is to disturb the communication.so how is this handled???

Comment: What do mean by disturbance? if any packets are dropped that will be handled by transport layer,

Comment: What do mean by disturbance?
1.suppose A and B need to communicate ,now C the attacker.
2.A sends the data to B and hashes the data and sign the hash with A's private key.
3.Now since be has the public key of A, He verify the sign using the p key of A.

Comment: 4.But C who is attacker intention is B should never receive a valid data. He modify only data and the hash remain same.
5.As now when B calculate the hash over the received data it will have mismatch with the original hash.so the message is discarded by B .so therefore the C's goal is achieved. This keeps on repeating in above steps(2-4).
6.Now how this problem is addressed is what question.

Comment: I dont think encryption scheme can handle this kind of scenario if someone is deliberately fiddling with data, receiver cant do much about it.

Answer (score 0):

When you hash a message or a file, you get a fixed length output.

```
this is a sweet sweet message to hash with sha1
```

Hash: `bef915c952a12cd9a0e4d7f352c7e795f9d5d0ec`

If you wanted to prove this message was unchanged, you could send the message (or file) along with the hash, and it the other side can calculate the hash for the message independently.

A good example of this is how Microsoft deals with signed executables. It uses an Authenticode hash, where there is some XML a the bottom of the binary. This is added after the original executable is hashed. Then windows can calculate the hash, later, and see if it matches.

Look [at PE Explorer to see how it works](http://www.heaventools.com/pe-explorer-digital-signature.htm).[image]